# Laravel update method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

According to the docs, I should be able to update records using `update()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#updates, but I'm getting the error `Method update does not exist`.

```
Client::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
```

Any idea why?

Comment: use ->fill($request->all())->save()

Comment: method fill does not exist...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is because you are using the query builder's method on a single model object. You cannot do this because the `findOrFail` method returns a single object that has nothing to do with query builder's methods.

Do it like this: `Client::findOrFail($id)->first()->fill($request->all())->save();`

Comment: You can use mass assignment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Are you sure that you got a real model object? Print the object's content with `var_dump(Client::findOrFail($id));` and send it here

Comment: object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#186 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(App\client)#196 (26) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["connection":protected]=> string(6) "sqlite" ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(5...

Comment: I got it. You are getting a collection instead of a single object. This shouldn't be this way but, use this: `Client::findOrFail($id)->first()->...`

Comment: Because here update function works on a single object as you are updating a single row by primary key

Comment: I don't know why the find method returns a collection; according to the docs, it should return a single instance: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models
Anyway, Great that it works, Please mark this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
Client::find($id)->update($request->all());
```

Or you can use this:

```
Client::where('id',$id)->first()->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Debug by using dd(Client::find($id));to see what results you are getting

Comment: Seems to be ok: Collection {#186 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => client {#196 ▼
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "sqlite"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => "5"
        "name" => "Aafasdfasf"
        "active" => "Yes"
        "created_at" => "2017-09-08 11:13:33"
        "updated_at" => "2017-09-08 11:13:33"
      ]
etc.

Comment: You are getting here a collection, it must be a single object