# Laravel 8: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to update some data from the DB, so I added this Controller method:

```
public function updateAnswer(Answer $anss)
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
           'answer' => 'required'
        ])->validated();

        $answer = Answer::findOrFail($anss);
        $answer->update($validate_data);
        return back();
    }
```

Now the problem is I get this error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.
```

So how to solve this issue?

Comment: `$answer()->update($validate_data)` here `$answer` is collection so make it DB instance like `$answer()`

Comment: Look into it i think this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115064/laravel-update-method-does-not-exist/46115168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already resolving `$anss` using [route-model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding).

```
public function updateAnswer(Answer $anss)
```

You are trying to call `findOrFail` with a model as an argument, which since `Model` implements `Arrayable` will return a `Collection`, thus breaking the update call.

See `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` findOrFail -> find -> findMany -> `return $this->whereKey($ids)->get($columns);`.

Try:

```
    public function updateAnswer(Answer $anss)
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
           'answer' => 'required'
        ])->validated();

        $anss->update($validate_data);

        return back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$anss` is already an Answer object so you do not need to query it from the database.

```
$anss->answer = $validate_data['answer'];
$anss->save();
```

or

```
Answer::where('id', $anss->id)
    ->update($validate_data);
```